# save and reload data while app is running ios

Tags: ios, save

i have made an app that uses arcgis, and want to make it so that i can save a list of the services it uses, and other arrays and objects and reload them while the app is running.
I have looked at plist, but not sure how to approach this.

What i intend to save is
an array of profiles, and an array of services.

Each profile has a name, legend array, zoom locations array, and the map services to use.

Each service will have a name, the url, and a string type for the type of service.

I need to make it so that i can change the profiles and arrays while the app is running, and the changes take affect after the data is saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

plists are pretty simple, you can organize items in arrays, dictionaries, NSNumbers, strings, etc.. It's just a matter of determining what to put where. Here's a mockup of what I would do:

```
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>userName</key>
        <string>myUserName</string>
        <key>legendArray</key>
        <array/>
        <key>zoomLocations</key>
        <array/>
        <key>services</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>url</key>
                <string>http://www.google.com</string>
                <key>type</key>
                <string>someServiceType</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Incase you don't know this, the above XML is what Xcode generates when you edit a plist, that's all it is an XML file :) If you prefer the standard view, here's a screenshot:

[image]

This creates an array full of dictionaries, each dictionary houses a string for user name, a legend array, an array for zoom locations, another array of dictionaries containing strings for url and service type.

Then as far as reloading the data goes, it's hard to say because you didn't specify how you're displaying the data. But, for example if you are using a table view, all you have to do is call `[self.tableView reloadData];` after you are done saving the new data. (assuming that the plist is your tables datasource)

If you need more help learning how to save a .plist to the documents directory here's a tutorial:
http://iosameer.blogspot.com/2012/08/handling-nsdocumentdirectory-of-your.html

Comment: thanks this helps out alot. I want to make it so that the services array is an array on its own. to do this i would have another dictionary item in the root called item 1 which would hold the url and type?

Comment: @user1596142 Actually if you wish to do this, I would recommend that you make a second plist all together. This will help you keep organized, and calling for items in that array will be simpler if they are the only objects in the array. And if my answer helped you be sure to mark it as correct :)